# Is it OK to have multiple merge steps in an Excel Power query?

Tags: powerquery

I have data from multiple sources - a combination of Excel (table and non table), csv and, sometimes, even a tsv.

I create queries for each data source and then I am bringing them together one step at a time or, actually, it's two steps: merge and then expand to bring in the fields I want for each data source.

This doesn't feel very efficient and I think that maybe I should be just joining everything together in the Data Model.  The problem when I did that was that I couldn't then find a way to write a single query to access all the different fields spread across the different data sources.

If it were Access, I'd have no trouble creating a single query one I'd created all my relationships between my tables.

I feel as though I'm missing something: How can I build a single query out of the data model?

Hoping my question is clear.  It feels like something that should be easy to do but I can't home in on it with a Google search.

Comment: No answers received but after further research, it looks like it's not possible to create a query from the data model except with some advanced, undocumented DAX / Cube function, which is currently beyond my level.
Shame.
Please feel free to respond if I have actually missed something.

Answer (score 0):

It is never a good idea to push the heavy lifting downstream in Power Query. If you can, work with database views, not full tables, use a modular approach (several smaller queries that you then connect in the data model), filter early, remove unneeded columns etc.

The more work that has to be performed on data you don't really need, the slower the query will be. Please take a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/best-practices) and [this one](https://sqlserverbi.blog/2021/02/14/doing-power-bi-the-right-way-4-power-query-design-best-practices/), the latter one having a comprehensive list for Best Practices (you can also just do a search for that term, there are plenty).

In terms of creating a query from the data model, conceptually that makes little sense, as you could conceivably create circular references galore.

Comment: Thank you.  I shall read these.  Unsure what you mean by 'heavy lifting'.  Ex Rqmnt: 
need one or more cols from each of 4 sources.  
Create basic queries for each.
Merge query for 2.  ‘Expand’ and get rid of unneeded cols.
Repeat to bring in 3rd source ; repeat again to bring in 4th. 
In Access, all the data is available in a relationship diagram and I just drag down the columns I need.  
The Data Model looks like the Access relationship screen so I thought that I could replicate that way of doing it rather than four repetitions.
Thanks so far.  TIA if any more you are able to offer.

Comment: The idea is that you weed out the unnecessary data as close to the source as you can. That's why I mentioned using SQL queries rather than full tables - the SQL query creating the view weeds out the data you do not need.

Comment: Also, the data model in Power BI or Excel functions like a mini-relational database. Once you make the necessary connections, you can pull the data into, for example, pivot tables or, in the case of Power BI, visuals. It is, therefore, not necessary to combine all of your individual queries into one big query in Power Query. On the contrary, I would keep them as short as you can, unless it is necessary to merge them there. Make the connection in the data model instead. This way, the queries themselves execute faster, because they don't have to wait on previous steps. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: PS. If I answered your question, please mark the answer as such. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry - I might be missing something.  My customer wants a list of students with data from various sources (a csv, an Excel a tsv and a table that's in my Excel file).  They haven't asked for analysis - just a list.
TBH I could copy / paste into Excel sheets and just use index/match formulae but I wanted it to be repeatable for when I get new files so went for PQ.  but how do I generate that list, which is essentially a multi-join-query?

Comment: Then do a multi-join query. I thought you were asking about multiple queries vs. just one in a Power Query scenario that connects to a data model. Best practices for that I have described/provided some links for. If all you want to do is come up with a list as the ultimate output, alternatively, you can use something like Python/Pandas.